# JFreeChart - PieChart missing value

Tags: jsf-2, jfreechart

I have web application with jsf.

After upgrade jfreechart from version 1.0.0 – 1.0.14 with the same code for some reason I cant see the value inside the PieChart.

```
// create a dataset...
    DefaultPieDataset dataset = new DefaultPieDataset();
    dataset.setValue("Category 1", new Integer(2));
    dataset.setValue("Category 2", new Double(27.9));
    dataset.setValue("Category 3", new Double(79.5));
 // create a chart...
    JFreeChart jfreechart = ChartFactory.createPieChart(
            "Sample Pie Chart",
            dataset,
            true, // legend?
            true, // tooltips?
            false // URLs?
            );

 <h:panelGrid style=" margin:0px auto">
    <p:graphicImage value="#{chartBean.jfreeContent}"/> 
</h:panelGrid>
```

Any idea why

Thanks

Comment: Cross-posted [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=115888).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed line 89 in [`PieChartDemo1`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/demo/PieChartDemo1.html#line.60) and saw no discernible difference.

```
dataset.setValue("Two", new Integer(10));
```

Comment: Can you say what the problem was?